# Can you test SetUp success/failure in Google Test?

Tags: googletest

Is there a way to check that SetUp code has actually worked properly in GTest fixtures, so that the whole fixture or test-application can be marked as failed rather than get weird test results and/or have to explicitly check this in each test?

Answer (score 15):

If you put your fixture setup code into a `SetUp` method, and it fails and issues a fatal failure (`ASSERT_XXX` or `FAIL` macros), Google Test will not run your test body. So all you have to write is

```
class MyTestCase : public testing::Test {
 protected:
  bool InitMyTestData() { ... }

  virtual void SetUp() {
    ASSERT_TRUE(InitMyTestData());
  }
};

TEST_F(MyTestCase, Foo) { ... }
```

Then `MyTestCase.Foo` will not execute if `InitMyTestData()` returns false.  If you already have nonfatal assertions in your setup code (i.e., `EXPECT_XXX` or `ADD_FAILURE`), you can generate a fatal assertion from them by writing `ASSERT_FALSE(HasFailure());` You can find more info on failure detection in the Google Test [Advanced Guide](http://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#checking-for-failures-in-the-current-test) wiki page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using static SetUpTestCase() (later renamed to SetUpTestSuite). At least in my case all tests in the test-case are still executed even if an assertion (ASSERT_EQ) in SetUpTestCase() fails.

Comment: For static SetUpTestCase (case mentioned above), the workaround would be to create a static boolean variable in the test class - e.g. static bool s_has_assert_failure - and in SetUpTestCase do s_has_assert_failure = HasFatalFailure(). Then in SetUp do ASSERT_FALSE(s_has_assert_failure).